# Make ex3 returning "nothing to be done for 'ex3'

Tags: c

I'm attempting to learn c from http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex3.html and during the exercise i am receiving a message that "Nothing to be done for ex3" when i try to compile the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int age = 10;
int height = 72;

printf("I am %d years old.\n", );
printf("I am %d inches tall.\n", height);

return 0;
```

Why am i receiving this error and how can i avoid it in the future?

Edit:

Thanks for the help in this, i've corrected the missing 'age' code and here is the makefile

```
 CFLAGS=-Wall -g

  clean:
    rm -f ex1
```

Comment: You didn't copy the code correctly, and from the message that perturbs you it seems that you didn't yet capture well how things should be compiled for these exorcises. Voting to close.

Comment: Minimal test cases. Title that precisely reflects the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error message. It just means that there is nothing to be done for target "ex3". Probably because it is already built. Post the makefile and we might be able to shed more light into the issue.

If the makefile has something like the following:

```
ex3:test.c
    gcc -o ex3 test.c
```

It means that the target ex3 depends on the file test.c; make will run the gcc command if and only if the last modified time of test.c is greater than that of ex3 (in other words, the source code is newer than resultant binary). You can `touch` the source code file to force a make:

```
touch test.c
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I've added the makefile info.

Comment: The makefile you posted is not complete; is this included in another makefile? There should be a line that starts with `ex3:` or some variable name with that value (as in `TGT=ex3`, <in another line> `$(TGT):`)

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to put age as an argument that is going to be printed. So, use:

```
printf("I am %d years old.\n", age );
```

instead of

```
printf("I am %d years old.\n", );
```